# Facebook Like Buttons and Apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to make Facebook apps. But I have some problems.  The documentation highlights this example: http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?v=app_161193133389

My apps are getting included as iFrames, even when I specify FBML - Coke's is more embedded.  The ["like button" generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) creates a different style of like button to Coke's. Coke's uses a built in Facebook CSS stylesheet.  Coke also has FB style links down the left side of their page.

Does anyone know how I could go about making an App like that? The documentation really does not cover it.  Even useful web-links would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the link to Coke is not an application, but a FB page. The like button showed is the standard like button that you get when you [create a page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?campaign_id=372931622610&placement=pghm&extra_1=0), which is different than the one that you obtain when you use FB social plugins.

They are very different things. A page represents something: a business, product, service, etc., while an application is, well.. an application. Note that pages can hold applications in their tabs, or just normal (and brand new) iframe tabs.

Regards

Comment: Well, if I click the link I don't see any application, just a regular iframe tab. And the links he's referring to... I bet they are the tab links in the new page layout